# Python 3 Download file no extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, download

I am trying to download an ics file from a site. When i enter:

```
https://.../timetable/export/
```

the file downloads.

How do i download this with python? Trying the request etc methods only returns a html of the page not the automatically downloaded file.

Thanks,

Itechmatrix

Comment: Is the page redirecting your request when you open the site in your browser?

Comment: When i open it in the browser my browser doesn't actually leave the current page - it just downloads the file @biobirdman